# How to accurately simulate key presses?

Tags: c#, wpf, input, simulate

How can I send key presses and mouse clicks to an application as if they were actually coming from the keyboard and mouse i.e. how can I fully simulate user input? I expect this will involve randomising the intervals that the keys are held down, raising events e.t.c. rather than using `System.Windows.Forms.SendWait`.

Comment: Perhaps if you explained what you are trying to achieve (a.k.a the purpose) we might be able to help you better. There are a lot of questions on SO related to "how to simulate key presses" and several others that will help you determine a random interval. Your question is stated in such a way that combining the answer to those two questions will help. If not, then please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to M.Babcock's suggestion I spent some more time searching on SO and eventually came across the [Widows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/). This will do precisely what I need.